# Terraform GKE google_container_cluster - should remove default node pool?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

Terraform [google_container_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster) example removes the default node pool.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "my-gke-cluster"
  location = "us-central1"

  # We can't create a cluster with no node pool defined, but we want to only use
  # separately managed node pools. So we create the smallest possible default
  # node pool and immediately delete it.
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
}
```

However, as the default pool is removed and there can be no node to deploy the system pods.

[image]

## Question

What is the good way to have a node to deploy the system pods?

1. Have a default pool with number of nodes is 1 and schedule system pods in the defaujlt node. Set the min autoscaling node count to 0 and do not schedule system pods in auto scaling pods
2. Remove the default pool. Set the min autoscaling node count to 1 so that system pods can be deployed in a autoscaling node.

## Node pool defnition

```
resource "google_container_node_pool" "primary" {
  name     = "${google_container_cluster.primary.name}-node-pool"
  project  = var.PROJECT_ID
  location = var.location

  cluster  = google_container_cluster.primary.name

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Node instantiation based on auto-scaling setting.
  # node_count and autoscaling are mutually exclusive.
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  node_count = var.autoscaling == true ? null : var.num_nodes
  dynamic "autoscaling" {
    for_each = var.autoscaling ? [1] : []
    content {
      min_node_count = var.min_node_count   # Set to 0 currently
      max_node_count = var.max_node_count
    }
  }

  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Node configurations
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  node_config {
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Service Account, the roles of which the node assumes
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    service_account = var.service_account

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Instance configurations
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    machine_type = var.machine_type
    preemptible  = var.node_preemptive
    disk_size_gb = var.disk_size_gb
    disk_type    = var.disk_type

    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # The K8S labels (key/value pairs) to be applied to each node
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    labels = var.labels

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]
    tags = var.tags
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are system pods that get deployed on each node, maybe kube-dns, kube-proxy however metrics server and other if running as deployment those can be running as single replicas on one of node.

> What is the good way to have a node to deploy the system pods?

Keep at least **1-2 node** for system pods like metrics server, ingress if you are installing inside kube-system etc.

> Have a default pool with number of nodes is 1 and schedule system pods
> in the defaujlt node. Set the min autoscaling node count to 0 and do
> not schedule system pods in auto scaling pods

There is no guarantee if you have set the autoscaling node count to 0 which means it will scale down. There are limitation with GKE about scaling down node you might need to take a look first however yes it's possible you can scale down to zero by updating PDB and checking other limitations.

**Limitation** : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#limitations

> Remove the default pool. Set the min autoscaling node count to 1 so
> that system pods can be deployed in a autoscaling node.

This is good if min count is 1 system pods should be up and running on that node, and when you deploy your application your nodes start scaling up as per need while system pods were already running.

You can also scale down to zero in that case if autoscaling is set and you deploy the application it will auto-start the application and system on available nodes so not much to worry about in that case also.

If you don't want to remove the default Node pool and keep running **1** Node, you can use this field : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#remove_default_node_pool